# How does CouchDB compaction affects /db/_changes?

Tags: couchdb

I have an application pulls CouchDB from the first doc to the latest one, batch by batch.

I tried compact my database from 1.7GB to 1.0GB, and `/db/_changes` seems the same.

Can anyone please clarify if CouchDB compaction affects /db/_changes ?

Answer (score 1):

All compaction does is remove *old* references to documents in a given database. The changes feed deals exclusively with write operations, which are unaffected by compaction. (since those writes have already happened)

Now, it should be noted that the changes feed will give you the `rev` numbers as well. Upon compaction, all but the most recent `rev` are deleted, so those entries in the changes feed will have "dead" links. (so-to-speak)

See the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/maintenance/compaction.html) for more information about compaction.